# Why do Atom snippets need four backslashes at once in their body in order to print a single backslash

Tags: coffeescript, atom-editor, backslash

I just realized this while setting up a snippet.

```
'.source':
  'shrug':
    'prefix': 'shrug'
    'body': '¯\\\\_(ツ)_/¯'
```

In order to print the typical `¯\_(ツ)_/¯` shrug, you need 4 backslashes. Using 2 backslashes doesn't cause any errors, but the backslash won't be printed. I would understand it if why you'd need 2, but why 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The four backslashes in atom snippets is due to snippets using the generic [CSON](https://github.com/bevry/cson) notation (Coffeescript style JSON).

It's well described in [this comment](https://github.com/atom/snippets/issues/128#issuecomment-94171361) on an issue from the [atom-snippets repo](https://github.com/atom/snippets)

> I think that four backslashes makes sense, however notationally
>   inconvenient.
>
> It has to do with the levels of interpretation a snippet goes through
>   before it ends up in your text buffer:
>
> 1. The snippet is declared in a CSON file, the parsing of string elements
>      in this format is "backslash sensitive" i.e. \n represents the newline
>      character and a \ is represented as .
> 2. The snippet then has to be
>      parsed by the snippet body parser. The parser uses one \ to escape the
>      following character, e.g. \ becomes . So the process goes as follows:
>
>    \ --CSON--> \ --BodyParser--> \
>
> The reason two backslashes used to work, was because the snippet body
>   parser never really handled escaped characters (the escape cases were
>   handled explicitly rather than in a generic way) this was why we had
>   bug #60.
>
> The process could be made more notationally friendly if the snippets
>   were stored in a custom format. Then we would have more control over
>   how it is parsed, such as not interpreting backslashes before they are
>   being fed to the body parser.